# Testing svg charts in Watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, testing, svg, automation, watir-webdriver

I am trying test if a chart has the correct title of 'Revenue'. I am using watir-webdriver to automate these test.

HTML code:

```
<nvd3-multi-bar-chart data="chartData" id="revenueChart" class="chart-render ng-isolate-scope" showxaxis="true" showyaxis="true" color="colorFunction()" interactive="true" xaxistickformat="xAxisTickFormat()" yaxistickformat="yAxisTickFormat()" yaxisshowmaxmin="false" callback="chartCreatedCallbackFunction()" nodata="">
<text x="20" y="20" text-anchor="start" class="statistics-title">Revenue</text>
<text x="20" y="40" text-anchor="start" class="statistics-title-total">Total: 1,222,140 USD</text>
```

All I could come up with is this:

```
if @browser.div(:xpath, '//*[@id="revenueChart"]/svg/text[1]').class == 'Revenue'
    print_green('Revenue Chart title           --- Pass')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-xpath alternative using `element` with a `class` locator:

```
if b.element(class: "statistics-title").text == "Revenue"
  # your message here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, try something like:

```
   if @browser.element(:xpath, '//*[@id="revenueChart"]/svg/text[0]').text == 'Revenue'
        print_green('Revenue Chart title --- Pass')
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got and unable to locate element error:


               unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"revenueChart\"]/svg/te
xt[1]"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: @Ahsan let's try someth about: `@browser.elements(:xpath, '//*[@id="revenueChart"]/svg/text').last.text`

Comment: unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"revenueChart\"]/svg/te
xt", :index=>-1} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)